# Are rubber shoes haram?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

I read somewhere that rubber shoes are haram, and I was wonder if it's true. The evidence is that sweatshops usually handle rubber and Muslims should not be anything like sweatshops so we should not wear clothes they make or material they often use (and according to that website, rubber is their most used material).

Comment: If you got by connections that far-fetched, then you wouldn't be allowed to wear anything made of any fabric used by sweatshops, which probably includes most fabrics.

Comment: You are literally an angel

Comment: I'm glad there are still Muslims that use logic out there

Comment: I'm not a Muslim, but glad this helped.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry...

Comment: Please post links to your sources or web sites

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a definite label to something like this as haram or halal.  It's best to support institutions that are not harming or abusing other people, the environment, etc.

We may be unwillingly supporting immorality just by paying our taxes.. but we have to exist in this world and we can only do our best and let Allah judge us based on our intentions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know and are sure that the product you are using is from sweatshops then that is a different matter.

But generally as per your question "`Are rubber shoes haram?`".  No, they aren't as whatever type of clothing is Haram is already mentioned in Quran and Hadith and no such evidence is available regarding rubber products.